# Order of events lazy loading the class itself

Tags: java

If I have this Java class, what exactly is the order of events upon construction/initialization?

```
class Start {

private Start s = new Start();

public Start(){} //constructor

}
```

when I call `new Start()`, isn't there some circular logic being invoked?

Comment: Yes, it is an infinite loop.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I was trying to achieve understanding that's all :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you got yourself a StackOverflowError here, since creating an instance of `Start` causes another isntance to be created when the `s` member is initialized, which creates another instance and so on.

```
private Start s = new Start();

public Start(){}
```

behaves as :

```
private Start s;

public Start() {s = new Start();}
```

To avoid such infinite constructor calls, you can pass an instance of `Start` to the constructor, or you can initialize the `s` member by some other method :

```
private Start s;

public Start(Start s) {this.s = s;}
```

or

```
private Start s;

public Start() {}

public initS () {s = new Start();}
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to lazy set a field is to use a getter. e.g.

```
class Start {
    private Start nested = null;

    public Start getNested() {
        return nested == null ? nested = new Start() : nested;
    }
}
```

This is not thread safe, but avoids infinite loops if used carefully.